How can display a welcome message above the Start Button in my touchpoint webchat cognigy?
I have created a Enpoint Webchat on the cognigy platform.
Before the home button I need to enter a welcome text.
To do that I followed these steps:https://support.cognigy.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408792943378-Display-a-welcome-message-above-the-Start-Button?input_string=how+to+injects+a+welcome+message+into+the+webchat+endpoint#enable-the-start-with-a-button-behavior-0-0
But I can't modify the embedding code (I only have read permission).
Do you know if I can add a welcome text from the Enpoint webchat options?
Thank you so much
